# What is the word that means -"to lose against a totally inexperienced opponent"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to explain the following idea:

> To lose any competition to an opponent who succeeds despite having no idea that they have overcome incredible odds against them to succeed.

Comment: You looking for a word that describes the winner or the loser? More context would help. Can you please provide an example sentence?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Title seems unambiguous in referring to the loser.

Comment: Yes @beldaz - I [edited](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/298987/revisions) it to bring in clarity. Thanks!

Comment: In that case @BiscuitBoy, Thanks for your unambiguous edit ;-)

Comment: Veteran XX was humiliated (suffered humiliating defeat) by newcomer YY in last night's match.

Comment: The most common words a loser uses to describe such an unfortunate circumstance: "Beginner's luck!"

Comment: Are we looking for a 'real' word? If we're talking electronic gaming, "pwned by the noob" would fit best.

Comment: "The other candidates were *schlonged* by the first-time campaigner".

Comment: I've heard this commonly called "being scalped".

Answer (score 26):

Not quite what is asked for, but my first thought.

> Aboyne (vb.)
>
> To beat an expert at a game of skill by playing so appallingly that none of his clever tactics or strategies are of any use to him.
>
> [urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=aboyne)

from The Meaning of Liff by [Douglas Adams](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/676457-aboyne-vb-to-beat-an-expert-at-a-game-of)

Comment: This was my first thought too :)

Comment: I'd upvote twice if I could for the *Meaning of Liff* reference, nicely done!

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: I haven't heard of this term before! A google search fetches results of a village in Scotland! How's it pronounced? Any etymology for this word? Can you update this answer with these details, please?

Comment: it is a village in Scotland, the book *Meaning of Liff* is  a mock dictionary. giving amusing descriptions for the names of geographic locations.

Answer (score 25):

The game itself or the act of losing can be called an **upset**.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upset) defines it as:

> an occurrence in which a game, contest, etc., is won by a person or
>   team that was expected to lose

[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upset) defines it similarly:

> an ​occasion when someone ​beats the ​team or ​player that was ​expected to ​win

Comment: This is a word I've actually heard before.

Comment: This is commonly used in UK.

Answer (score 19):

Well to succeed despite idiocy is called pulling a Homer.

[image]

To lose to someone pulling a Homer might be called pulling a Frank Grimes.

> I'm saying you're what's wrong with America, Simpson. You coast through life, you do as little as possible, and you leech off of decent, hardworking people like me. Heh, if you lived in any other country in the world, you'd have starved to death long ago. You're a fraud, a total fraud.
>
> ―Frank Grimes
>
> [simpsons.wikia.com](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Frank_Grimes)

Comment: A good candidate, but I don't think it's achieved as wide cultural cachet as "cromulent" or "embiggen" :)

Comment: I had always thought "to pull a homer" was to pull off a baseball homerun..  something I had considered an "unlikely but huge success".. now I feel silly.

Comment: Though it is perfectly cromulent to upvote anything to do with the Simpsons, despite the popular culture reference I would hate to think that this answer is the best option that the rich English language has to offer.

Answer (score 18):

This could be considered **beginner's luck**.

The online [Cambridge Dictionary defines it as:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beginner-s-luck)

> unexpected ​success ​experienced by a ​person who is just ​starting a ​particular ​activity

Comment: Would it be with an apostrophe, "beginner's luck"?

Answer (score 6):

[**David and Goliath**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/david-and-goliath)

> used for describing a situation in which a small person or organization defeats a much larger one in a surprising way

Macmillan Dictionary

From the biblical story in which Goliath, a giant, is killed by the boy David with a stone.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath

---

You can find more information about this term on this very website - [What do you mean by the phrase David vs. Goliath?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185908/what-do-you-mean-by-the-phrase-david-vs-goliath)

Comment: not a good example!! David was small, but was neither inexperienced nor naive! He was very experienced and had a good plan. He was more of a hero than lucky naive don't-know-how winner.

Comment: And the OP never said anything about inexperience or naivety

Comment: Goliath never had a chance. David killed him with superior technology.

Comment: Goliath had about the same odds of winning that fight as the guy who pulled a sword on Indiana Jones, and for the same basic reason.  The only surprising thing about the battle was that he never seemed to realize just how screwed he was until it was too late.

Comment: @MasonWheeler & kevincline - I'll take you word for it. I was simply explaining the meaning of the idiom.

Comment: From the original story, It's worth noting that a more religious interpretation would say that for David, his victory came because he was a champion of God. Not because of his plan, or because he had a slingshot while Goliath had a javelin, or because of his size. So, using "David and Goliath" to describe the situation implies a sense of fate that David *will* win regardless of anything else - because of who is on his side, rather than just being a mere underdog who happened to win on his own power alone.

Comment: @Charon I believe David had killed many animals (lions?) that threatened his sheep. He already had a lot of experience with his slingshot, even though he'd never killed a person before.

Comment: I have no interest in the biblical story. This is not a theology forum. I am talking about the popular phrase which originated from it - its definition is written above. Please note that the OP made no request about inexperience. Please understand that I was making no theological commentary.

Comment: Apologies, the OP did mention inexperience. David was a young boy, Goliath was an experienced and fearsome warrior. Therefore, in relative terms, David was inexperienced.

Answer (score 5):

In Australia, this is sometimes called "doing a Bradbury", and while this might not be exactly what you were looking for, the story is too good not to be shared!

> In Australian English ‘to do a Bradbury’ is to become the unlikely winner of a contest or to accidentally achieve success, (...)
>
> So what did the original Bradbury do to achieve his place in the Australian lexicon?
>
> In an unlikely series of events, short-track speed skater Steven Bradbury became the first Australian to win a gold medal at a Winter Olympics. (...)

[The whole story on ozwords.com](http://ozwords.org/?p=5912) (The video is worth watching!)

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you are looking for an unorthodox or an informal phrase or a word, you could use "to pull a homer". (Previously suggested by CandiedOrange) 
For Ex: Donald Trump becoming a president can serve as a prime example of someone pulling a homer.

And if you want something more formal(something that's taken from an animated sitcom), i believe "Fluke" comes close to the word you are looking for.

Comment: Well, this has been already suggested by CandiedOrange

Comment: They say imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.

Answer (score 2):

To Blow it -

He champion blew it against a total novice.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blow-it

Answer (score 1):

Despite the word's original usage pointing toward behaving dishonestly, I've seen the word 'cheated' used to describe a loss in the manner the OP has mentioned.

> "He was cheated out of winning the title by a rookie."

Comment: This may be a common usage, but it has a lot of unwelcome associations. For instance, making this statement suggests that the speaker believes that a longtime veteran of a competition "deserves" to win, regardless of whether their skill or performance is superior. That's not even getting into the somewhat inevitable implication that the rookie in question actually cheated...

Answer (score 1):

In my native dialect, we would say he "fluked it".  I don't know whether that's in use outside of the Canadian Prairies.

Answer (score 1):

How about **[flub](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flub)**? In its sense of "to fail utterly at something you should have succeeded easily."

Possibly also **choke**, although that doesn't quite capture the competition itself, just the act of playing far below usual skill level.

Answer (score 1):

*A few ideas:*

**Abased** (pp)

> Reduced to a low state, humbled, degraded. *

**Upset** (vi)

> To overturn; to overthrow; to overset; as a carriage.

(*Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary* (1828))

**Botch** (n)

> ...
>
> 3. Work done in a bungling manner; a clumsy performance; a piece of work, or a place in work, marred in the doing, or not properly finished; a bungle.

**Bungle** (n)

> A clumsy or awkward performance; a botch; a gross blunder.

**Blunder** (vi)

> 1. To make a gross error or mistake; as, to blunder in writing or preparing a medical prescription. Swift.
> 2. To move in an awkward, clumsy manner; to flounder and stumble.

(*Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary* (1913))

*Some related ideas:*

Flub, fail, falter, fluke, choke, drubbed, humiliated, embarrassed, disappointed, stumble

Answer (score 1):

**To snatch defeat from the jaws of victory**. [Wiktionary.org defines it as](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snatch_defeat_from_the_jaws_of_victory)

> (idiomatic) To suddenly lose a contest one seemed very likely to win, especially through mistakes or bad judgment.

Answer (score 0):

[**Choke**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/choke)

> To fail to perform effectively because of nervous agitation or tension, especially in an athletic contest

This is from the perspective of the person who loses (which seems correct by your question), but is somewhat specific and doesn't address that there is an opponent with less skill (or an opponent at all).  Notwithstanding that, to me it gets at the gist of losing against someone inferior despite superior skill.

Answer (score 0):

at my old fencing club we used to call the tendency for beginners to do unreasonably well against seasoned fencers "muppet factor"